# Unable to set the grids accurately in material ui react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to make a sample application to test react material ui and I am stuck while using grids. I have two grids in my app inside the main grid container. One grid is for the lists and the other is for the map view. now whenever the list items increases it shows a scroller on page to move it up/down which I don't want since I want the map to stay stable on the screen covering 100% height and 80% width. But as soon as the list size increases the map also becomes scrollable in the page. How can i fixit? Moreover my list buttons can also move over the list subheader which I don't know how i can stop.

my code is
...

```
import React from "react";
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  Button,
  ListSubheader
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./styles.css";
import Icon from "../src/icon.png";
import shadow from "../src/shadow.png";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      location: [
        {
          id: 1,
          machine: 1,
          lat: 51.503,
          lng: -0.091
        },

        {
          id: 2,
          machine: 2,
          lat: 51.56,
          lng: -0.094
        }
      ],
      center: [51.505, -0.091],
      zoom: 11,
      marker: null
    };
    this.clickAction = this.clickAction.bind(this);
  }

  Icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: Icon,
    shadowUrl: shadow,
    iconSize: [38, 50],
    shadowSize: [50, 64],
    iconAnchor: [22, 34], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
  });

  clickAction(id, lat, lng) {
    this.setState({ marker: id, zoom: 16, center: [lat, lng] });
  }

  render() {
    const styles = {
      Paper: {
        padding: 20,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: "90%",
        overflowY: "auto"
      }
    };

    return (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Paper style={styles.Paper}>
            <List
              style={{ width: "20%", float: "left" }}
              subheader={
                <ListSubheader component="div">
                  <div>
                    <h1> my appplication </h1>
                  </div>
                </ListSubheader>
              }
            >
              {this.state.location.map(({ id, machine, lat, lng }) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <ListItem
                      key={id}
                      button
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.clickAction(id, lat, lng);
                      }}
                    >
                      Id {id} <br />
                      machine {machine}
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>a</ListItem>
                  </>
                );
              })}
              <Button style={{ position: "sticky", botton: "0", left: "0" }}>
                sign out
              </Button>
            </List>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>

        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {this.state.location.map(({ lat, lng, id }) => {
            return (
              <Marker position={[lat, lng]} icon={this.Icon}>
                <Popup> {id} </Popup>
              </Marker>
            );
          })}
        </Map>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

...

my sample app is here https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-mountain-ogf4v?file=/src/App.js:0-3720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove these:

```
  padding: 20,
  marginTop: 10,
  marginBottom: 10,
```

add `height: 100vh` to `styles` and give a  `style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}` to your `ListSubheader` comp.

[Updated Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unable-to-set-the-grids-accurately-in-material-ui-react-xjkql)

Comment: No problem. Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and/or upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: hello, my whole text on list is basically inclined towards the left side even though there is still so much space on right and same goes for buttons, they are clickable only from the very left end. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: First thing you need to do is to accept the answer as you said it worked and solved your problem. Second thing, open a new thread to ask your new question as it is completely different from the original post.

Comment: Accepting an answer means you click on the green arrow tick underneath the vote buttons. Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You haven't done that. You should always accept the answer if it solved your problem in every question you get a satisfying answer that solved your issue. Not only this one but in all answers in your other posts as well if they have solved your issue.